# way to edit the component style in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to use bootstrap css. What is the correct way to change the css style of some element?

1. going into bootstrap.css, getting class name and changing or adding value for height, width, left etc
2. Adding inline css for that element in html file?

I am trying to reduce the height of header and footer in this example for last 4 hours :(

[Code pan Example](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/hxatC)

If someone exactly give change for this example then highly appreciate.

Want to reduce height of footer and header part

Answer (score 0):

You have to overriding CSS classes

```
//reduce the height of header 
    .navbar-default {
        height: 50%; // Choose your height
    }

//reduce the height of footer
#footer {
    height: 100px;// Choose your height
}
```